# JQuery UI DatePicker: how to set value to arbitrary string?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, struts2

I'm looking for a way to make JQuery UI DatePicker to allow setting the date to any arbitrary string, including an invalid date. I need this to give user a chance to change the date he may manually enter, in case this date was in an incorrect format

**Steps:**

- the user manually enters the incorrect date `28/13/2012` (date format is `dd/mm/yy`, month 13 is invalid)
- the user validates the form
- struts2 displays the same form again with a message

**Expected:** On page redisplay, field is filled with `28/13/2012` and a message "incorrect date format"

**Actual:** The field gets becomes empty

Would'nt it be better for user to get his old incorrect value `28/13/2012`? How can we achieve this?

Thanks

---

## Addition:

JSP code:

```
<s:textfield name="fromDate" cssClass="datePicker" theme="simple"/>
<s:textfield name="toDate" cssClass="datePicker" theme="simple"/>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.datePicker').datepicker({
        autoSize: true,
        dateFormat: '<s:text name="date.datePicker.dateFormat"/>',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        dayNamesMin: '<s:text name="date.datePicker.dayNamesMin"/>',
        monthNamesShort: '<s:text name="date.datePicker.monthNamesShort"/>'
    });

    // Gestion du la dépendance entre date de début et de fin
    $('input[name="fromDate"]').datepicker( "option", "onClose", function( selectedDate ) {
        $( 'input[name="toDate"]' ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    });
    $('input[name="toDate"]').datepicker( "option", "onClose", function( selectedDate ) {
        $( 'input[name="fromDate"]' ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    });

});
```

Java code (Action class):

```
private String toDate;
private String fromDate;
// + getters and setters
```

Comment: How do you initialize the datepicker? And the struts? Can you show some code in order to help you to hook the validation code?

Comment: Sure. I edited the question to include JSP and JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a quick quirk to display the old incorrect date

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // initialize datepicker
    $('input.datePicker').datepicker({
        autoSize: true,
        dateFormat: '<s:text name="date.datePicker.dateFormat"/>',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        dayNamesMin: <s:text name="date.datePicker.dayNamesMin"/>,
        monthNamesShort: <s:text name="date.datePicker.monthNamesShort"/>
    });

    // Do all your JQuery UI datepicker-related stuff here
    // (...)

    // force old date. Useful when user types a date with month=13 for exemple
    $('input[name="fromDate"]').val('<s:property value="fromDate" />');
    $('input[name="toDate"]').val('<s:property value="toDate" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that your proposed interface is better than what's shipped with jQuery UI. Unfortunately, there's no particularly simple solution. The jQuery UI widgets don't have a particularly orthogonal design, as you can see by the 50-odd options defined for DatePicker. In particular, validation is not a separate policy object, nor is the behavior with respect to validation even configurable.

I dealt with analogous issues during version 1.7 and 1.8 before they had a supported Menu widget. Before they had a pre-release, I used a semi-custom implementation, altered from some prototype code on the web. This was fine, since the product was still in development. After the pre-release, I converted over, and then converted over-and-over as the widget changed slightly with each minor pre-release. So I suspect you're stuck with a custom or semi-custom implementation.

As for how to proceed, I'd recommend hacking in a new option, something like `requireValid`, that gives you the behavior you're looking for. You'll want to ensure that `getDate` has a sane behavior, returning `null` if the current text is not a valid date, for example. You'll likely need to alter `setDate` to allow assignment of an invalid date string. Go over the other methods to see what the effect of allowing a transiently-invalid value would do, and do something reasonable.

Then, if you don't want to maintain this code yourself, get your changes into the release. That will require more than a little rhetoric. You'll need to argue your case well, and probably loudly.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I finally found another lighter quirk (see my other answer)